# Hue Saturation Intensity Histogram

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am using Debian Linux Siduction. I have an image in jpg format which I can read and convert to arrray. But I want to convert the image from RGB color model to HSI color model and then plot a histogram for the saturation and intesity parameters of the HSI image. I have tried to plot the intesity part but I'm not sure about the accuracy of my results. I have included the code.

```
import scipy
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import numpy as np
from scipy import misc
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/ref.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
arr=(array.astype(float))/255.0
img_hsv = colors.rgb_to_hsv(arr[...,:3])

lu1=img_hsv[...,0].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,1)
plt.hist(lu1*360,bins=360,range=(0.0,360.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='r', label='Hue')
plt.title("Hue")
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu2=img_hsv[...,1].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,2)                  
plt.hist(lu2,bins=100,range=(0.0,1.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='g', label='Saturation')
plt.title("Saturation")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()

lu3=img_hsv[...,2].flatten()
plt.subplot(1,3,3)                  
plt.hist(lu3*255,bins=256,range=(0.0,255.0),histtype='stepfilled', color='b', label='Intesity')
plt.title("Intensity")   
plt.xlabel("Value")    
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

here is the histogram i have got by taking bin size 100 but I'm not sure what should be the appropriate size for my data

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [hsv\_to\_rgb isn't the inverse of rgb\_to\_hsv on matplotlib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732270/hsv-to-rgb-isnt-the-inverse-of-rgb-to-hsv-on-matplotlib)

Comment: also see https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2566 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2569

Comment: @tcaswell I looked up the sources you mentioned but this is different. I intend to separate the saturation component and then plot its histogram

Comment: @tcaswell I have modified the code and tried to plot H S and I paramateres separately but is there a way I can verify the correctness of my histogram

Comment: why do you convert to hsv twice?

Comment: Yeah you're right I missed that I'll make the changes

Comment: @tcaswell Is there any way in which I can verify the output of my results so that I know its correct

Comment: put in an image you know the distribution of.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have any such image

Comment: Then make one.  you can specify what ever you want in hsv space, convert that image -> rgb and then run it through your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
img = scipy.misc.imread("/home/subhradeep/Desktop/test.jpg")
array=np.asarray(img)
# convert, but this is buggy 
im_hsv = matplotlib.colors.rgb_to_hsv(array[...,:3])
# pull out just the s channel
lu=img_hsv[...,1].flatten()
plt.hist(lu,256)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly img_hsv[...,1] refers to
and my data for saturation ranges from 0 to 1 so how do I modify the plt.hist(lu,256) for the histogram to display correctly

Comment: What part of it do you not understand?

Comment: The value for H S and I paramters are in the range 0-1 but the bin size here is 256 how do I modify that so that my histogram displays the data correctly using the right number of bins